# What OST is played in episode 685 when Fujitora is talking about colosseum's warriors teaming up?

Tags: one-piece, music

What OST is playing in the background of episode 685 right after the end of the first half of the episode when Fujitora is talking about colosseum's warriors teaming up?

Comment: Hi, welcome to A&M Stack Exchange. I assumed the image is the scene when the song is playing? If so, I replaced it with textual information because images are not indexable/searchable. If not, then consider [edit]ing the question and add more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This OST comes from **One Piece Movie 5**, its name is : **The Marine Swordsman's Battle Cry**

Here is a link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOkvZQknY6E